# Rocket.Chat developer setup shows no error but no UI

Tags: rocket.chat

I have installed Rocket.chat (server and client ) on my Mac for development. Everything appears correctly installed `I20170624-15:51:27.314(1)? ➔ System ➔ startup
I20170624-15:51:27.315(1)? ➔ +-----------------------------------------------+
I20170624-15:51:27.316(1)? ➔ |                 SERVER RUNNING                |
I20170624-15:51:27.317(1)? ➔ +-----------------------------------------------+
I20170624-15:51:27.318(1)? ➔ |                                               |
I20170624-15:51:27.319(1)? ➔ |  Rocket.Chat Version: 0.57.0-develop          |
I20170624-15:51:27.320(1)? ➔ |       NodeJS Version: 4.8.3 - x64             |
I20170624-15:51:27.320(1)? ➔ |             Platform: darwin                  |
I20170624-15:51:27.321(1)? ➔ |         Process Port: 27271                   |
I20170624-15:51:27.321(1)? ➔ |             Site URL: http://localhost:3000/  |
I20170624-15:51:27.322(1)? ➔ |     ReplicaSet OpLog: Enabled                 |
I20170624-15:51:27.322(1)? ➔ |          Commit Hash: b34e081123              |
I20170624-15:51:27.323(1)? ➔ |        Commit Branch: develop                 |
I20170624-15:51:27.323(1)? ➔ |                                               |
I20170624-15:51:27.324(1)? ➔ +-----------------------------------------------+`

However connecting to localhost:3000 either through the browser or through the client, the screen is blank and the progress dots keeps whirling forever. There is also no log from the server. I am not getting to see the login screen. I can use curl however.

Comment: Funny enough, the rest API works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about this problem since there is not much info on the question (checking your browser for errors would be a good idea), but there are things you can try:

- Updating to the latest develop version;
- Doing a `meteor npm install` before running meteor;
- Doing a reset on your local database using the `meteor reset` command;

Comment: there e no errors on the browser. I am using Safari. And I am able to connect to RocketChat servers.

Comment: Rocket.chat has been having trouble with safari for a while, I think the next release will have a fix for that, for now you can use another browser, like chrome or firefox.

Comment: Same problem with chrome. And the rocket.chat Mac app.